# How to include html code with reactive MathJax elements in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown, mathjax

I am working on a shiny app that is intended to help students. It generates solution for each student with some equations using student specific input values.

The problem is that the MathJax equations are rendered as regular text, see the minimal example and this image:

[image]

*Any idea how dynamic MathJax elements could be rendered properly?*

**My current approach:**

- use an `rmarkdown` document (`solu_template.Rmd`) with input parameter (`params$student`) to create student specific markdown file;
- render the markdown file and include it in the `ui`.

Reactive, dynamically changing MathJax elements are feasible as [this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html) shows. However, I would like to use more complex files and keep the convenience of preparing the solution template as an `rmarkdown` file.

**Additional attempts:**

- direct use of the html file generated by `render()`, but I do not know how to include it in the `ui` as a dynamically changing component;
- read the generated html file with `readLines()` and use `htmlOutput` to display it; no success, just a pile of code.

*So, using this approach the question is how to render/display a dynamically changing html file?*

All ideas, suggestions are welcome!

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)

shinyApp( 

  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("student", "Student:", 
      choices = c("Student1", "Student2", "Student3")),
    actionButton("show_solu", "Run!"),

    hr(),
    withMathJax(),
    htmlOutput("solu")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$solu <- eventReactive(input$show_solu, {
      rmarkdown::render("solu_template.Rmd",
        quiet = F, clean = F,
        params = list(student = input$student))

      solu <- renderMarkdown("solu_template.knit.md")
    }
    )
  }
)
```

**solu_template.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Solution"
params:
  student: Student1
output:
  html_document:
    theme: readable
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
S = list(Student1 = 1, Student2 = 2, Student3 = 3)
s = S[[params$student]]
```
## Heading

Student dependent initial value:
$s = `r s`$

Some nice reasoning which yields to this equation:

$R = s^2 + \sqrt{2} = `r signif(s^2 + sqrt(2), 3)`$
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution with the `renderMarkdown()` approach:

The following line should be added to the html code generated by `renderMarkdown()`, this way the browser will know that the output should be rendered considering MathJax elements:

```
"<script>MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);</script>"
```

Regarding the above example, this should be added to the end of the `server` function of **app.R**:

```
solu = paste(solu, "<script>MathJax.Hub.Queue([\"Typeset\", MathJax.Hub]);</script>")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use knitr I don't see why this wouldn't work. I haven't used 'dynamic-math' but I use a fair amount of notation in Rmd files rendered inside a shiny app used for students. Take a look at the repos linked below and let me know if you have any questions.

https://github.com/vnijs/shiny-site
https://github.com/vnijs/quizr

Comment: Thanks for the links, great examples, you did some very interesting things - that I've never thought of - with combining Rmd and Shiny. Regarding the OP, actually `render()` internally uses `knitr` functions, and still the rendering was not working, only after adding the line given in my answer. I saw that you also made some tinkering with the `knitr` output in `inclRmd()`, and you also made a comment that image rendering(embedding) is not included. Have you solved this issue yet? I am facing a similar problem as well. (I will take a closer look at you `inclRmd()`)

Comment: I didn't want to use embedded images actually. I would avoid it unless you need to send a single file to students or something. Shiny will put the images somewhere anyway.